# Using XAML (for WP7) how can I obtain a horizontal rule overlaid with centered text that will resize with orientation changes?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml

The kind of effect I am looking to achieve is,

```
------------------- some text ---------------------
```

such that if the phone goes landscape, the rule will stretch (hence AFAIK the `Line` element is not suitable).

Can this be done easily in XAML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok figured it out,

```
<Grid Margin="0">
    <Border BorderThickness="0,2,0,0" BorderBrush="White" Margin="0,15,0,0" />
    <Border Background="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Padding="5,0" >
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="some text" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

The first `Border` top margin has to be adjusted such that it aligns at the midpoint of the text.